# How to use image as button in ionic

Tags: android, ios, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

My objective is to use image as a button in ionic. I first used a-tag to link between page. But when I clicked on the image. There is no button activated effect. So I switch to button-tag

I have tried using

```
<button class="button button-clear" style="background-image:url('img/myImage.jpg'); background-size:cover"></button>
```

But the button height stay the same. So it won't show full size image.
I have tried

```
style="font-size:100px;"
```

and

```
style="line-height:100px;"
```

But nothing seems to work.

I also tried adding my own css

```
.Test-up {
  border :none;
  padding : 0px;
}

.Test-down {
  opacity: 0.5;
  border:0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

and added below code into my index.html

```
<button ng-mousedown="class='Test-down'" ng-mouseup="class='Test-up'" class="{{class}}" href="#">
```

and below code to my controller

```
$scope.class = "Test-up";
```

as I tried from http://codepen.io/Leiron/pen/ztawA
But it doesn't work with ios or android. So what should I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this.

```
 <img src="img/myImage.jpg" style="width : 100% ; height : 100%" ng-click="nextpage()" >
```

this shoud to the trick you can have the height and width as your wish.

Make sure you give the correct path to src field.

Comment: I tried it but the ng-click happen after I release my finger. I want the image background to change its opacity a bit while I'm touching the button. Just like when touching ion-item. There will be a change while I am holding down my finger. It is different.

Comment: if you want like ion item then put this image in ion-item so that is will be same as you think like `<ion-item> <img..... > </ion-item>` let it have only one item in the list

Comment: This does not work ...

Answer (score 12):

You can try this way -

```
<button  (click)="click()" block>
     <img src="assets/img/scan_btn.png">
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Ionic 2**

Place your icons in www/assets/images then

```
<img src="assets/images/icon.png" style="width : 100% ; height : 100%" ng-click="nextpage()" >
```

Comment: it seems this works in ionic 2 with "(click)"  instead of "ng-click"

Comment: you can also use (tap) or (click) instead of ng-click for Ionic 3

Answer (score 2):

#### Ionic 4

```
<a routerLink="/user/details" routerDirection="forward">
   <img src='assets/images/icon.png'  />
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Ionic 5**

You can also use **ion-card** element :

```
<ion-card class="welcome-card" [routerLink]="['/tabs/tab3']">
    <ion-img src='/assets/VC-Button-calendario-01.svg'></ion-img>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this

`<button ng-mousedown="class='fb-down'" ng-mouseup="class='fb-up'" class="{{class}}"> <img src="your_image_path" alt="" title="" /> </button>`

If still you face any problem in css and in anyhting let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With this you can use image button for routing.

```
<button onclick="location.href='/pageToRoute/param'" block>
   <img  src="imagePath/imageName.jpg">
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the image in a div Container.

```
<div (click)="yourFunction()">
    <img>
</div>
```

this has the advantage over an ion-button that the image itself is not changed and has no blue border.

Answer (score -1):

See the pen @ http://codepen.io/jeggu96/pen/NRaxj
Hope it helps :) `<button ion-button clear (click)="nextPage()"><img src="image path" alt=" " /></button>`