# how to create a graphic button with ionic and html

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I am developing an App with ionic and cordova.

I just want to create a graphical button.

I'm thinking of using something like:

```
<button class="button button-positive button-large">
  large Text
</button>
```

So, how do I add an image to my button?

Many thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37629131/how-to-use-image-as-button-in-ionic

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS Material is both a UI Component framework and a reference implementation of Google's Material Design Specification. This project provides a set of reusable, well-tested, and accessible UI components based on Material Design.

refer this link-https://material.angularjs.org/latest/

add this   `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.6.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>`

or

http://ionicmaterial.com/