# Adding image to header and use image as button

Tags: css, cordova, ionic2

I added an image to my header and to me button in browser i am able to view it correctly but whine i run the app to my mobile using `cordova run android` 
In my header i could not see image i am getting a blank space, and also space for button but no image is visible but on clicking it executes function.

```
<ion-header color="dark" >
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col col-1>
                    <img  src="assets/img/logo.png" > 
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col style="padding-top: 19px;" col-5>
                   My title
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-title>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button ion-button icon-only>
                 <ion-icon name="log-out" (click)="logout()"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
 <ion-row>
        <ion-col style="padding-left: 45%;">
            <p>Choose language</p>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-10>
            <button (click)="changeItaly()" clear ion-button>
                 <ion-icon name="italyFlag"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
            <button (click)="changeEnglish()" clear ion-button>
                <ion-icon name="englishFlag"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

**css**

```
.ion-ios-customicon,
.ion-md-customicon {
  content: url(../../assets/img/ui/logo.png);
  width: 32px;
  height: 49px;
  padding: 6px 4px 2px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.ion-ios-italyFlag,
.ion-md-italyFlag {
  content: url(../../assets/img/ui/italy.png);
  width: 49px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 6px 4px 2px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.ion-ios-englishFlag,
.ion-md-englishFlag {
  content: url(../../assets/img/ui/english.png);
  width: 49px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 6px 4px 2px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

[image]

> I am able to see these images in my browser but i could not see it in my mobile. could someone help me

Comment: you have not return any click function on your image how come you are  on clicking it executes function.

Comment: Right now i need a image to be displayed in the place of a buton

Comment: you mean instead of logout button you need image there right now i see only one image avaliable in your header

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37629131/how-to-use-image-as-button-in-ionic check this one may be it will give you some idea

Comment: which image are you refering to ? log-out or flag?

Comment: inspect height of image / image containers. they might not have it. might have to set fixed height using height:100*px*, instead of height:auto/%.

Comment: check now @admcfajn,  i could see those images j-logo, and 2 flag but could not see those things in mobile

Comment: I couldn't trigger the event from your codepen, my comment was just speculation.

Comment: Did you wind up getting this sorted out? Sorry, was up too late last night. I don't see any reason why the styles wouldn't be working. Have you tried adding a background color? That would tell you if it's the elements not loading or just the background-images not loading.

Comment: Elements gets loaded but the images are not loading instead i get a blank space in the place of those flags @admcfajn

Comment: We could change this: `content: url(../../assets/img/ui/logo.png);` to `background-image: url(../../assets/img/ui/logo.png);` or try changing this: `url(../../assets/img/ui/logo.png)` to this `url(../assets/img/ui/logo.png)` If it's just the images broken the path might not be correct.